# How to only print a part of the JSON like string in Python

Tags: python

I am getting this output (as a string) below from certain commands. I need to get the value of `Value`.

Output (string):

```
[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"bitesize-troubleshooter-2/CONSUL_TEST-2","Flags":0,"Value":"dGVzdF9kYXRhLTI=","CreateIndex":338871,"ModifyIndex":341922}]
```

I am using `jq` as below to get (filter) only the value of `Value` (i.e:`dGVzdF9kYXRhLTI=`) as below:

```
jq '.[] | .Value' "[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"bitesize-troubleshooter-2/CONSUL_TEST-2","Flags":0,"Value":"dGVzdF9kYXRhLTI=","CreateIndex":338871,"ModifyIndex":341922}]"
```

This gives error as below:

> jq: error: Could not open file [{LockIndex:0,Key:bitesize-troubleshooter-2/CONSUL_TEST-2,Flags:0,Value:dGVzdF9kYXRhLTI=,CreateIndex:338871,ModifyIndex:341922}]: No such file or directory

Before I execute this command in `python` I need to make sure it really works in terminal, then I can implement it using `python`

How can I only filter out the value of `Value` in my output? When I grep it, it still gives the whole string.

Comment: jq expects a *file name*, so write `[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"bitesize-troubleshooter-2/CONSUL_TEST-2","Flags":0,"Value":"dGVzdF9kYXRhLTI=","CreateIndex":338871,"ModifyIndex":341922}]` into a file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using Python, why not use Python to parse the string instead of executing `jq`?

```
import json
jsonString = '[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"bitesize-troubleshooter-2/CONSUL_TEST-2","Flags":0,"Value":"dGVzdF9kYXRhLTI=","CreateIndex":338871,"ModifyIndex":341922}]'
parsed = json.loads(jsonString)
value = parsed[0]['Value']
```